# Google Contacts, eTags, Updated changing on every access

Tags: google-contacts-api, etag

I am trying to use the eTag from a call to get Google Contacts. Since there is an eTag on the "top level", I was hoping that I could check it to determine if anything in the contacts dataset had changed. Here is my request:

Request URL: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/?max-results=0
Request headers:
    Authorization: Bearer 
    Depth: 1
    GData-Version: 3.0
    Content-Type: text/xml

My thought is that if I request for 0 results, I'll have just the information I need. I can check the eTag against the one that I stored, and if there is no change, there were no changes to any contacts. The XML I get back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed gd:etag="&quot;QXYyfzVSLyt7I2A9XRRQFkwJRAA.&quot;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch" xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
 <id><email address here></id>
 <updated>2015-02-11T00:09:00.897Z</updated>
 <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
 <title>Joe's Contacts</title>
 <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://www.google.com/"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/joe%40ihouseweb.com/full"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/joe%40ihouseweb.com/full"/>
 <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/joe%40ihouseweb.com/full/batch"/>
 <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/joe%40ihouseweb.com/full?max-results=0"/>
 <link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/joe%40ihouseweb.com/full?max-results=0&amp;start-index=1"/>
 <author>
  <name>Joe</name>
  <email>joe@ihouseweb.com</email>
 </author>
 <generator version="1.0" uri="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds">Contacts</generator>
 <openSearch:totalResults>42</openSearch:totalResults>
 <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
 <openSearch:itemsPerPage>0</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
</feed>
```

Everything looks good.. except that each time I make the call, the updated date and the eTag come back different. I can make 10 calls in a row, and each time the eTag is different. Is this not a valid way to use the API? If the eTag comes back different every time for anything, then I can't use it to determine if something has changed. Isn't that what the eTag is for?

andy

Here is a sample - I am making the request above 10 times, at 5 second intervals. This is my personal account, so I'm pretty sure that no-one is changing any values on me. Note that the eTag and "updated" values are different each time. The first column is the time I made the request (PST), the second and third are the resultant eTags and updated values.

16:38:30 : "SHYyfTVSLyt7I2A9XRRQGEoORAQ." : 2015-02-14T00:38:29.895Z

16:38:36 : "RHY-fjVSLyt7I2A9XRRQGEoORAU." : 2015-02-14T00:38:35.856Z

16:38:42 : "QHk9ezVSLyt7I2A9XRRQGEoORAY." : 2015-02-14T00:38:41.763Z

16:38:47 : "Rns6cTVSLyt7I2A9XRRQGEoORAY." : 2015-02-14T00:38:47.519Z

16:38:53 : "Qnw-fzVSLyt7I2A9XRRQGEoORAc." : 2015-02-14T00:38:53.257Z

16:38:59 : "SXc5ezVSLyt7I2A9XRRQGEoORAc." : 2015-02-14T00:38:58.923Z

16:39:05 : "RXg5ezVSLyt7I2A9XRRQGEoORAA." : 2015-02-14T00:39:04.623Z

16:39:10 : "QX06cTVSLyt7I2A9XRRQGEoORAE." : 2015-02-14T00:39:10.319Z

16:39:16 : "R346eDVSLyt7I2A9XRRQGEoORAE." : 2015-02-14T00:39:16.010Z

16:39:22 : "QHgyfjVSLyt7I2A9XRRQGEoORAI." : 2015-02-14T00:39:21.696Z

Comment: When an entry or feed changes, its ETag changes as well. Check this link for more information on Etags https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference?csw=1#ResourceVersioning

Comment: That is what I expect, but as shown in my updated information above, I get a different etag each time I just query the feed. Odd... in the link you posted, it says that the eTags on feeds will always be weak. But I'm looking at the feed etag, and, per the link, these are not weak eTags (don't start with "W/").

Comment: I got the word from Google Support... eTags on feeds are always weak, but yes, there is a problem, in that the eTag on the Contacts feed is weak, but not appropriately marked as weak (W/). They are looking into it.

Comment: @AndyWallace Have you found the solution now ?